How to disable oauth token auto refresh in Angular PWA?
I'm trying to disable, or at least skip, the auto refresh of the oauth token in my Abp.io Angular PWA app under certain conditions.
In my case, the auto refresh trigger even if the app is offline which result in an erroneous page displayed.
In the best case, I would like to check my connectivity before trying to refresh my token. I tried to use an interceptor, but it doesn't fully worked and I didn't like this solution, feels like an hacky method.
From what I saw, the auto refresh come from the package angular-oauth2-oidc, method setupAutomaticSilentRefresh, and it can be stopped with stopAutomaticRefresh, but with the abp.io Angular template, it seems we don't have access to those methods.
Anyone already had this need and know how to deal with ?
